# using sed, remove only one character before number match

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a text file like so:

```
text-text-text-7.7.1-text
text-text-text-text-1.2.4-text
text-text-1.2.4-text
```

I wish to replace character before numbers to space. So the expected output should be

```
text-text-text 7.7.1-text
text-text-text-text 1.2.4-text
text-text 1.2.4-text
```

How would I do that using sed?

I have tried using **sed -E 's/-/ /g'** but it replaces all - with spaces

```
text text text 7.7.1 text
text text text text 1.2.4 text
text text 1.2.4 text
```

as well as **sed -E 's/-[0-9]/ /g'** and output looks like this:

```
text-text-text .7.1-text
text-text-text-text .2.4-text
text-text .2.4-text
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you tagged your question `awk` this is task for [gensub](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html). Let `data.txt` be name of your file, then you do:

```
awk '// {print gensub(/-([0-9])/, " \\1", 1)}' data.txt
```

getting output:

```
text-text-text 7.7.1-text
text-text-text-text 1.2.4-text
text-text 1.2.4-text
```

This does use capturing group and reference to it in replacement - like @Thomas answer and does replace first occurence. It is worth noting that `gensub` allow you to easily change any occurence - if you put `2` as 3rd argument it will replace 2nd occurence and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Since you want only *one* application of the rule, don't use the final `/g`. And to only apply the replacement when there is a number following, you should include that in the matching rule:

```
sed 's/-\([0-9]\)/ \1/'
```

Since you don't want the actual digit to be replaced, the above expression captures it in a group `\(...\)` and reinserts it via the `\1` expression.